# Skip over cell(s) in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a user interface in Excel (I know, not ideal; but it's a start), and the way I have it laid out has a few blank cells(i.e. N12 thru N14) between two cells that are "input" cells(i.e. N11, N15). I'm wondering if there is any IF statement or something of that effect that would allow me to TAB over cells N12-N14 by only hitting the "TAB" key once?

Concurrently, I have a blank cell(i.e. O11) below N11 that I would like to skip over to get to P11 by hitting the "ENTER" key once?

Any suggestions?

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: Select the input cells -> right-click -> Format Cells -> Protection tab -> Uncheck "Locked" -> OK.  Then right-click the worksheet tab name -> Protect Sheet -> Uncheck "Select locked cells" -> OK.  Now a user can only select cells you have specified as unlocked, and will automatically skip over other cells when navigating via Tab or Enter keys.

Comment: ^^ This is what you want.

Comment: it was a long process, but that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to sure, but you could use something along these lines.

Call this on workbook open maybe

```
application.OnKey "{tab}","Supertab"
```

Have this in a module

```
Sub SuperTab()
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this pretty much mapping Ctrl+Right to the TAB key? I'd find that ...maddening! =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, it does seem that way :)